# Duplicate data after refresh in Laravel 8

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to add data to form in the Laravel project. In the first time add data they add correctly to my database. But I'm refresh the page data will be duplicate automatically.
[Add data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tThEK.png)

[After saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Fba5x.png)

after this refresh
[Refresh msg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ALxr.png)

Duplicate data
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mkdzi.png)

[Controller code](https://justpaste.it/413ww)

[page code](https://justpaste.it/1wq1n)

[Database](https://justpaste.it/1kuwb)

Comment: Instead of simply rendering a view after saving, you should redirect to the view after saving. Also, please paste code into the question directly. We don't like clicking on shady links unless we have to.

Answer (score 0):

after save data just redirect to the index route from your web.php file.

```
$fxd_asset_details->save();

return redirect()->route('fxdasthddetails');
```

and let route handle the rest, once you controller 'index' manage the data to be retrieved from db